# JSONDecodeError while trying to open JSON files in Python

Tags: python, json

I have the following JSON file from **scraping** content on Twitter:

```
{"id": 911265668921733120, 
"conversation_id": "911265668921733120",
"created_at": "2017-09-22 19:27:20 EAT", 
"date": "2017-09-22",
"time": "19:27:20",
"timezone": "+0300", 
"user_id": 61177265, 
"username": "sircalic", 
"name": "Dan",
"place": {"type": "Point", 
"coordinates": [-1.18998912, 36.77644171]},
"tweet": "Bitcoin ain't stabilizing at $4,500 any time soon LOL but it's good to stock for long term.", 
"language": "en", 
"mentions": [],
"urls": [], 
"photos": [],
"replies_count": 0,
"retweets_count": 0,
"likes_count": 0,
"hashtags": [],
"cashtags": [],
"link": "https://twitter.com/sircalic/status/911265668921733120",
"retweet": false,
"quote_url": "",
"video": 0,
"thumbnail": "",
"near": "Nairobi", 
"geo": "", 
"source": "",
"user_rt_id": "",
"user_rt": "",
"retweet_id": "",
"reply_to": [],
"retweet_date": "", 
"translate": "", 
"trans_src": "",
"trans_dest": ""
}
```

But when I try opening it in Python with the following code:

```
current_file = str(os.getcwd()) + '/NewYork2017-09-30 00:00:00.json'
l = json.load(open(current_file))
```

I get the following error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 1036)
```

I have done some research on the error and I kept getting the error that there is something wrong with the characters but I can't seem to find a solution.

Is there anything that can be done to fix it?

Comment: works without error for me

Comment: FYI Scrapping means throwing away. I think you mean ‘scraping’